# How do I use Java to incrementally read line from file?

Tags: java, io, readfile

I want to use Java to read line by line from input file. The logic of the code should be:

> 1. The *loadFile()* in the *log class* reads the first line. The *deltaRecords* stores the first line
> 2. In the *Main class*, I call *loadFile()*, and it only upload the data in the *deltaRecords*, which is the 1st line. The *loadFile()* waits until the first line has been analyzed by *testRecords()* in *Main class*
> 3. The *loadFile()* in the *log class* reads the 2nd line. The *deltaRecords* stores the 2nd line
> 4. In the *Main class*, I call *loadFile()*, and it only upload the data in the *deltaRecords*, which is the 2nd line. The *loadFile()* waits until the 2nd line has been analyzed by *testRecords()* in *Main class*
> 5. The *loadFile()* in the *log class* reads the 3rd line. The *deltaRecords* stores the 3rd line.

For example, my input file is:

```
TOM 1 2 <br/>
Jason 2 3 <br/>
Tommy 1 4 <br/>
```

After I read TOM 1 2. I need to halt the process and do the analysis. Then I continue to read Jason 2 3.

Here is my current code. In the *log class*, I defined *loadFile()* to read the input line by line. In the *Main class*, I defined *testRecords()* to analyze.:

```
public void loadFile(String filename) {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        Main main = new Main();
        String line = br.readLine();
        int count = 0;
        while (line != null) {
            if (line.length() == 0) {
                line = br.readLine();
                continue;
            }
            LogRecord record = new LogRecord(line);
            //add record to the deltaRecord
            deltaRecords.add(record);
            //here I need to wait until it has been analyzed. Then I continue read
           //initial the deletaRecords and add current line to the old record

            existRecords.add(record);
            line = br.readLine();
           }
       }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("load log file failed! ");
            e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

In my main function, I call loadfile:

```
Log log = new Log();
log.loadFile("data/output_01.txt");
QueryEngine.queryEngine.log = log;
testRecord(log);
```

Could anyone tell me how to solve this problem? Thank you very much.

Comment: You need to call `readLine()` inside the loop regardless of the line length. Otherwise you aren't getting anywhere.

Comment: BufferedReader provides a readLine() method that will do as you want.

Comment: Re `here I need to wait until it has been analyzed. Then I continue read` in the code, do you mean that it will be _analyzed_ by another thread ? Your description doesn't seem to hint to anything asynchronous but that code comment and one of the answers seem to assume that. In my opinion you could improve the question by making this explicit either way.

Comment: @ SantiBailors, Thank you for your comments. I rewrite my description. I'm not sure if I need to create two different process to handle this problem. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it using a **Consumer** lambda function as input on your **loadFile** as follow:

```
public void loadFile(String filename, Consumer<LogRecord> lineAnalyzer) {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
            Main main = new Main();
            String line = br.readLine();
            int count = 0;
            while (line != null) {
                if (line.length() == 0) {
                    line = br.readLine();
                    continue;
                }
                LogRecord record = new LogRecord(line);
                //add record to the deltaRecord
                deltaRecords.add(record);
                //here I need to wait until it has been analyzed. Then I continue read
                //Analyze line
                lineAnalyzer.accept(record);
                existRecords.add(record);
                line = br.readLine();
           }
       }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("load log file failed! ");
            e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

Then when you call the loadFile function you can specify the analysis line logic as follow:

```
Log log = new Log();
QueryEngine.queryEngine.log = log;
log.loadFile("data/output_01.txt",logRecord -> {
    System.out.println("Starting analysis on log record "+logRecord);
    // Analyze the log record
    testRecord(log);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments. The logic of my code is: after the loadFile() reads the first line, the loadFile() waits until the first line has been analyzed by testRecords() in other class.  So at this step, the loadFile() only load the first line. After testRecords() finished, the loadFile() continues to read the 2nd line.  So it's not actually about reading a specific line.

Comment: Basically you need something that allows you to start the analysis after each line has been read from file but calling the method **testRecord** method defined on the MainClass ( and waiting for it before to read the next line ). Is it right? If yes, take a look on my latest update on my question. I've added the **testRecord(log)** instruction on loadFile the lambda function body ( the second input parameter ).

Answer (score 0):

## You don't need to read a line when you create your line variable

Replace

```
String line = br.readLine();
```

with

```
String line = null;
```

## You can use value assignment inside a conditional

Replace

```
while (line != null) {
```

with

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
```

## In the case of empty lines continue

Replace

```
            if (line.length() == 0) {
                line = br.readLine();
                continue;
            }
```

with

```
            if (line.length() == 0) {
                continue;
            }
```

## How your code should look like

```
String line = null;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.length() == 0) continue;
    //Analyze your line
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use scanner to read the file and process line by line. I have attached snippet code below.

```
public void loadFile(String filename) {
        try {
            Scanner sc= new Scanner(new File(filename));
            while (sc.hasNext()) {
                String line = sc.nextLine();
                LogRecord record = new LogRecord(line);
                //add record to the deltaRecord
                deltaRecords.add(record);
                //here I need to wait until it has been analyzed. Then I continue read next line
               //Place your code here
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fe) {
            System.err.println(fe);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I know that. But how to "wait" between each line scan? I mean, Before the Scanner go to the 2nd line, I need to load 1st line first.

Comment: You just use this code.. It will not go to second line till you method is not completed.